# Easiest way to implement a simple web-service project?

Tags: javascript, web-services, rest, soap

I am creating an add-on for my browser that should report the websites you visit automatically to some remote server (no server response needed).

The browser extension is written in Javascript, so I suppose XHR requests are available for me to make. The only thing that comes to mind for me is to create a RESTful web-service and use that but I am thinking that there must be an easier way? or is SOAP the way to go?

Comment: Working in a browser, HTTP requests (REST) is pretty much as simple as it's going to get. SOAP is way more complex and overkill for this.

Comment: What language will you be using for the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with REST and you like Java then I'd recommend jersey: http://jersey.java.net/

If you really want simple and aren't concerned with following all the REST principles you can just make a simple perl cgi or php script and just post the request to it.

Comment: Thanks, this did give me some options here